# TryCatch ConcurrentModificationException catching `30% of the time

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, concurrentmodification

I'm using an iterator to remove a projectile from a list if it goes out of the border of my JPanel. Before using the iterator it would not work, but with the iterator it works so long as I put the method into a try-catch for a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The code now works, and successfully removes the projectile from the list, but about 30% of the time, the catch hits and causes a stutter in my program. I don't know why it only catches sporadically, but in the limited time my professor was able to look at it he thought it may have been a synchronization issue.

Here is the loop running my program:

```
private void executeGameLoop() 
        {

            long nextFrameStart = System.nanoTime();
            while(panel.getRunning()) 
            {
                do 
                {
                    panel.repaint();
                    nextFrameStart += FRAME_PERIOD;
                } while(nextFrameStart < System.nanoTime());

                long remaining = nextFrameStart - System.nanoTime();
                panel.update();

                if (remaining > 0) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(remaining / 1000000);
                    } 
                    catch(Throwable e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is called by the loop at `panel.update`. It handles updating the projectiles for now:

```
public void update()
        {       
            randX = (int)((Math.random() * getWidth()) - (int)(Math.random() * getWidth()));
            randY = (int)((Math.random() * getHeight()) - (int)(Math.random() * getHeight()));

            int sizeX;
            int sizeY;

            try
            {
                Iterator<Projectile> it = shots.iterator();
                for(Projectile a : shots)
                {
                    if(!a.equals(null))
                    {   
                        sizeX = a.getDisplayX();
                        sizeY = a.getDisplayX();

                        if((!checkCoords((int)a.getX(), (int)a.getY(), sizeX, sizeY)) && a.hasTarget())
                        {
                            a = null;
                            if(it.next().equals(null));
                                it.remove();
                        }

                        else if(a.hasTarget())
                        {
                            a.update();
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            catch (ConcurrentModificationException e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Catch"); } 
        }
```

These last two method are my mechanism for creating the projectile:

```
private void createProjectile(int x, int y)
{
    total++;
    if(shots.size() < shotCount)
    {
        Projectile temp = new Projectile(randX, randY);
        temp.setTarget((x + temp.getSprite().getDisplayImg().getWidth() / 8),
                        (y - temp.getSprite().getDisplayImg().getHeight() / 8));
        temp.setHasTarget(true);
        shots.add(temp);
        msg("Target: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    createProjectile(e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```

Any insight about why this is happening or how to rectify it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should work on preventing the cause ConcurrentModificationException rather than catching it.

Comment: And you should post the stack trace.

Comment: FWIW, you have two major problems that are both likely causing `ConcurrentModificationException`s. You need to fix both the problem I identified and the one @dnault found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an open `Iterator` in your `for` loop (plus the extra `Iterator it`), and you're adding values in `createProjectile`. You need to either make both blocks `synchronized` on `shots`, or (my recommendation) make a copy of `shots` to do your drawing from:

```
List<Projectile> shotsToPaint;
synchronized(shots) { shotsToPaint = [`ImmutableList`][1].copyOf(shots); }
```

and apply appropriate synchronization in `createProjectile`. Depending on how performance-sensitive it is, you can either synchronize the whole method on `shots` or synchronize on `shots`, check the size, create the new `Projectile` in an unsynchronized block, and then synchronize to recheck the list size and add.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was unaware that the loop has an implied `Iterator` as pointed out by dnault. Using this implied `Iterator`does remove the `ConcurrentModificationException` issues. However, I'm still very inexperienced with any Synchronization. Can you point me in a direction to learn how to apply Synchronization here?

Comment: @Caboose I don't have a tutorial to hand, but the basic rule is that you need to scrutinize the use of any object that might be used from multiple threads; objects that hold state for graphics operations are a red flag. Always assume that any two operations on it might be interrupted, so that in `createProjectile` someone might modify `shots` after you check `size()` but before you `add(Temp)`.

Comment: @Caboose in particular, consider whether it makes sense to add a projectile in the middle of an update. If the answer is "No", then you can enforce this by making sure both methods are synchronized on the same lock. If all of the methods you've shown us are in the same class, you can simply add a "synchronized" keyword to the definitions of update() and createProjectile().  More about synchronization here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 3):

The for loop is one of the problems. When you create a loop like this:

```
for (Projectile a : shots) {...}
```

The compiler implicitly converts it to:

```
for (Iterator<Projectile> i = shots.iterator; i.hasNext();) {
    Projectile a = i.next();
    ...
}
```

So in total you have TWO iterators. The first one is created when you explicitly call `shots.iterator()`, and the second is created implicitly by the compiler in the for loop.

One cause of `ConcurrentModificationException` is when someone else modifies a list at the same time you are iterating over it. Your professor suspected a synchronization issue because usually the "someone else" is in a different thread, but in this case the "Someone else" is the *other iterator*.

EDIT: As chrylis has pointed out, there is interference from a different thread as well.