# Android try/catch didn't work

Tags: java, android, try-catch

There is system in my Android app for sending reports about uncaught exceptions (google play account doesn't belong to me). Some days ago I've got following error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
onlineorganizer.Adapter.fillGrid(Adapter.java:332)
onlineorganizer.Adapter.access$6(Adapter.java:314)
onlineorganizer.Adapter$1.run(Adapter.java:131)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

It appears inside following method:

```
private void fillGrid(GridLayout layout) {
    grid = layout;
    Iterator<View> iter = null;
    boolean isCellsEmpty;
    if(cells == null) {
        cells = new LinkedList<View>();
        isCellsEmpty = true;
    } else {
        iter = cells.iterator();
        isCellsEmpty = false;
    }
    if(dates != null) {
        for (final String date : dates) {
            JSONObject event = events.get(date);
            View view;
            if(isCellsEmpty) {
                view = null;
            } else {
                if (iter.hasNext())
                    try {
                        // HERE
                        view = iter.next(); //exception appears HERE
                        // HERE
                    }
                    catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                        Log.e("next in list", e.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                else
                    view = null;
            }
            if (event!=null && event.has("evid")) {
                view = getEventView(date, view);
            } else {
                view = getEmptyView(date, view);
            }
            if(isCellsEmpty && cells != null) {
                cells.add(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, exception appears inside `try/catch` block, that should handle it. And now you can guess what question I have.

Why `catch` block didn't catch exception?

Comment: what other places are you using `cells` in the adapter class?

Comment: @Nambari why the exception is thrown? The method should return from `catch` block.

Comment: Which line is 332?

Comment: `view = iter.next()` @shmosel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to eliminate the reason the issue is happening. You can synchronize access to the datastructure or use a thread safe datastructure.

See for example:

[TryCatch ConcurrentModificationException catching `30% of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752320/trycatch-concurrentmodificationexception-catching-30-of-the-time)

http://nerddawg.blogspot.hk/2004/09/concurrent-modification-of-collections.html

Comment: Yes, you are right about thread safity, but there is no time for refactoring project. Thats why there is just placed `try/catch` block here.

Comment: I see. For a quick fix, try to put a synchronized { .. } block around the iterator code.

Comment: I like solution with iterating copied array. I guess there would not appear any exception again, but it is not answer for the main question - why exception wasn't catch?

Comment: @Ircover, what do you mean by exception wasn't catch? How you found that catch was not executed? Same code with dummy data returned out of the method for me (upon concurrent modification exception).

Comment: In my question I wrote stacktrace, which I got from my crash reports system. It means this exception was handled by my `UncaughtExceptionHandler` implementation. It is actually not a normal behavior for `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

your condition : 
`if (iter.hasNext())` 
is out of try block put that in try block then check it .hope it will help you :)

Comment: I don't think so, stack trace says: `java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)` not `java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.hasNext`

Comment: it doesn't matter. If the exception has been thrown by `hasNext()` method, it would have been shown in the stack trace.